# change background color of div using css

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

Is it possible to change the background color of a div using css?

Code so far:

CSS

```
.div{
background-color: #000;
}

.live .div:not{
background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Javascript

```
function change(){
$("body").addClass("live");
}
```

HTML

```
<div onclick="change()">change</div>
<div>...</div>
```

Comment: Use the `background` or `background-color` css property.

Comment: did you mean this: $('body').css('backgroud-color','someColor');  ?

Comment: Seems like the code you posted worked! Or did it? We appreciate a specific problem statement.

Comment: i want to change only div color.

Comment: E,g onclick play btn change background-position http://www.saavn.com/s/#!/s/album/hindi/Rabba_Main_Kya_Karoon-2013/8BbAnIRCPJc_

Comment: `:not` *what*? The syntax is `:not(simpleSelector)` (eg `:not(.className)` or `:not(h2)` for example). Reference: [negation pseudo-class `:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be confused about what you're trying to accomplish. @fedxc probably has the right solution. But if you're trying to change the color only of the div that was clicked, this will do it:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        Change this div!
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
}

div.live{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('live');
});
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7rbdg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
.div{
  background-color: #000;
}

.live .div:not{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Also, are you going to use `<div class="div">...</div>` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good what you're doing, just make sure to use background-color.  I made a thing that does that with a random color, if it helps. http://gascalculator.ca/randomcolor

I used pure javascript though, I'm not familiar with jquery

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do is change the body background color when you click the DIV.

Since you are using jQuery I would trigger the background color change with a .click() function on the DIV.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="div">
        Change my world!
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.div{
background-color: #000;
color: white;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".div").click(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color", "#ddd");
});
```

Here is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/7rbdg/).